# Inserting an image name and number into database

Tags: php, android

I keep getting the error that an object of class mysqli could not be converted to string.

Here is the code for inserting an image name and number in database:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "u785741983_boy";
$password = "789456";
$dbname = "u785741983_tuner";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
   echo "Connection Error";
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$image = base64_decode($_POST['image']);
$number = $_POST['number'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO `Person`(`Picture`,'Name','Number') VALUES ('$image','$name','$number')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo $sql;
} else {
    echo $conn;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: In what line the error appears?

Comment: Is the question related to android??

Comment: object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in android screen

Comment: yes saravInfern

Comment: you really saving the image on the database?

Comment: yes   if you having a bettter way tell me Masivuye Cokile

Comment: better way is to save the image in the directory in the server then store the image url location on the db

Comment: okay thnks it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do `echo $conn` in the else statement, because the connection is an object.

Yo have to do `echo mysqli_connect_error()` or `echo  $conn->connect_error()`

Look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php